# Taking a System.Type in and return an IEnumerable of this type

Tags: c#, generics, casting, ienumerable

I have a method which returns all enum values (but this is not material). The important bit is that it takes `T` and returns `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
    private static IEnumerable<T> GetAllEnumValues<T>(T ob)
    {
        return System.Enum.GetValues(ob.GetType()).Cast<T>();
    }
```

or

```
    private static IEnumerable<T>  GetAllEnumValues<T>(T ob) 
    {
        foreach (var info in ob.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
        {
            yield return (T) info.GetRawConstantValue();
        }
    }
```

To use this method you need to call it with an instance of the class - in this case with any value from the enum we want to explore:

```
    GetAllEnumValues( Questions.Good );
```

I would like to change the signature of the method to take a `System.Type` in and to be able to call it like this:

```
    GetAllEnumValues( typeof(Questions ));
```

I don't know how the signature would look like:

```
    private static IEnumerable<?>  GetAllEnumValues<?>(System.Type type)
```

and how to apply casting or `Convert.ChangeType` to achieve this.

I don't want to have to call `GetAllEnumValues<Questions>( typeof(Questions ));`

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5):

Why not to create a open generic type, which you can specify with an enum, like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> GetAllEnumValues<T>() 
{
    if(typeof(T).IsEnum)
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
    else
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>(); //or throw an exception
}
```

then having enum

```
enum Questions { Good, Bad }
```

this code

```
foreach (var question in GetAllEnumValues<Questions>())
{
    Console.WriteLine (question);
}
```

will print:

```
Good
Bad
```

Comment: Hehe, you keep improving your answer, but it was correct from the start. So obvious when I see it now, I just over-engineered my code :)

Comment: @Tymek I'm just trying to bring some details, for example exception handling. Devil is in the details, as you may know;)